# jQueryUI dialog bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, overlay

Is this a bug in jQueryUI's dialog or is there some reason this is happening?

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wXer/)

The title bar on that fiddle is way too big.

Notice that if you resize it snaps back to the correct position.

For the record, html:

```
<div id="wrapper"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    font-size: 15px;
}​
```

js:

```
$('<div title="the title">content</div>').dialog();​
```

Is there any way around this? Can I manually call the `resize` callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a more recent stylesheet. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6wXer/4/)**. You're linking to ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css and the most recent is 1.8.18 (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css).

Comment: i know this is an old question, but still. Do you know why this dialog is not working with new jq version 1.8? Just change jsFiddle to include jquery 1.8 and your example is not working.

Comment: Looks like you used new jquery ui(1.8.23), with old one(1.8.18) it's not working

Comment: Where's 1.8.18 in that fiddle?